# SQL GroupBy with Where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

The below query returns any User who existed Where transaction_date > '3/1/2017' and has sum(AMOUNT) > 3000 from all dates.

I want to return only users who have had sum(AMOUNT) > 3000 AFTER 3/1/2017.  In other words, user needs to have sum(Amount) at least $3000 from only transactions after 3/1/2017.

```
 SELECT   User
 FROM     Source
 Where transaction_date > '3/1/2017'
 GROUP BY User
 HAVING   sum(AMOUNT) > 3000
```

Comment: No, your query does what you intend to do, not what you describe it as doing.

Comment: When I look at sum(amount) for all users with above query, I see users who have <$3000.

Comment: . . You should provide sample data and desired resuls.

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE` is processed *before* the aggregation.  So, your query is only considering transactions after that date.

I would strongly advise you to use ISO-standard date formats and write the query as:

```
SELECT User
FROM Source
WHERE transaction_date > '2017-03-01'
GROUP BY User
HAVING SUM(AMOUNT) > 3000;
```

If you have a problem with the results, it could be due to the date formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Use to to_date function for formatting date and => for at least your needed amount.

```
SELECT   User
FROM     Source
Where transaction_date > to_date( '3/1/2017','dd/mm/rrrr')
GROUP BY User
HAVING   sum(AMOUNT) => 3000
```

Answer (score 0):

USE >= in Gordon's code if you want to include 3000

```
SUM(AMOUNT) >= 3000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

SELECT User
FROM Source
WHERE date(transaction_date) > '2017-03-01'
GROUP BY User
HAVING SUM(AMOUNT) > 3000;

If problem persists please share your data format in the table.